# c# project target platform of 64bit machine

Tags: c#, c++, 64-bit

I have a c# project which is linked with c++ project. I am running my application in 64 bit machine now. How to configure the c# project to 64 bit? There is some compatibility issue I am facing in 64 bit machine now.

Previously I was running my application in 32 bit machine. It was working perfectly. In 64 bit machine the linking fails as part of my c++ code is giving the right output. when the c# linking code is hit the execution stops without throwing any errors.

Comment: You can force your managed code project to a processor architecture in the project properties of visual studio.

Comment: @JonasKöritz how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set-up your project to target x86 or x64 specifically (depends on your C++ library).

[image: Visual Studio Project Properties]

Comment: I did that. Still facing the same issue. Is it coz c# and c++ are dll?

Comment: What Kind of error message are you receiving? What if you debug the application on the affected PC?

Comment: I am getting any error message. While debugging my c++ code is executed and when the linking code(with c#) is encountered debugging stops.

Comment: both are for 64bit. When i checked in registry i saw the tlb file generated from c# is registered in win32 even though i changed the platform target into 64bit